# building a java code on a linux server via a windows

Tags: java, linux, user-interface, x11

I want to run my java project on a linux server via a windows machine and I'm using WinScp to connect to the server. Since my project has a simple gui, I got this error: "No X11 DISPLAY variable was set" and then I used this commad:

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0
```

and the next error is :"Cannot connect to X11 windows server...."
When I connect to the same server via a linux machine, everything is fine. It seems something is wrong with building a gui in windows machines. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Microsoft Windows != X11/X-Windows. You would need to be running an X Windows Server on your Microsoft Windows machine. Note this is off-topic for StackOverflow as it really has nothing to do with Java or programming; you may have better luck searching on http://superuser.com

Comment: @BrianRoach: Thanks a lot. Would you please to explain it more? OK. I will post on superuser.com

Comment: Basically, you need this: http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux, and most *nix operating systems, use X Windows for their GUI platform.  It's what manages the windows and paints it to the screen.  X Windows has the ability to do remote desktop, using something called X11.

In order for X11 to work, you have to tell your *nix source which display to send to where, using something like "export DISPLAY=10.88.0.1:0.0", which basically says "create a shell variable called DISPLAY, and set it equal to something".  When an X11 app starts, it sees that Display variable and uses what it says to "draw" itself.  The example here basically says "send display 0.0 to the IP address 10.88.0.1".  You would obviously replace the IP in this example with YOUR client IP.

The last piece is that you need something to INTERPRET the X11 requests once they are sent.  That is where you need an X11 client of some sort.  There are lots out there, some you have to pay for like Humming Bird, some are free.  Bottom line, you need something to accept the X11 signal you are sending from your Linux device.  Word of caution: X11 is usually REALLY slow.

Comment: Little of this applies since he's talking about trying to xhost to a (MS) windows box. He stated he doesn't have a problem with *nix (and ... 0:0 is appropriate when tunneling through ssh). And the part about X11 being slow is pure rubbish.

Comment: Your right.  If you are using X11 tunneling, you don't need to specify the IP you are coming from.  Also, X11 forwarding isn't any slower than most other remote desktops, but people new to it often complain that it's "unresponsive".  It is slower than running the desktop local.  Despite those issues, what I suggested is still correct.  You still need to indicate where the display needs to go, you still needs some client to receive that, and you are going to see performance differences when running displays over a network.